# Backbone.js listenTo(model,'change',callback) callback not reached after splitting files with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm splitting up my working Backbone.js application, into seperate files for models, views and routers.

Starting my Router:

```
window.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        require(["routers/my-router"], function (MyRouter) {
            var myRouter = new myRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        });
    }
});
```

In my Router file `routers/my-router.js`, I am listening to a change event of a Model:

```
define(function (require) {
"use strict";
var $           = require('jquery'),
    _           = require('underscore'),
    Backbone    = require('backbone');

return Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        require([],
            function(){
                var model = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
                self.listenTo(model, 'change', self.callback);
                model.trigger('change');
            }
        );
    },

    callback: function() {
        console.log('callback reached!');
    }
});
});
```

**I receive the following errors for different ways of defining the callback:**

- `self.callback`: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
- `callback`: `Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined`
- `this.callback`: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onManualDestination' of undefined`

This question was edited after Yurui's answer.

Comment: depends on the purpose of this piece of the code...shouldn't it be `return new Backbone.Router.extend({})` ?  and in your example i don't see how or where you are triggering the change on that model.

Answer (score 1):

ok, a few things.

to execute a Router's initialize method, you will have to create a Router instance, and then use Backbone.history.start(), like so:

```
//define router:
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({});

//instantiate a router
new Router();

//start router! 
Backbone.history.start();
```

In your example, the router is not instantiated, nor started. 
also, the model change is not triggered.

here's my working example:

```
//define a model.
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//define a router
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
            var myModel = new Model({});
            self.listenTo(myModel, 'change', self.callback);

            //triggers change right away so you can see the callback output
            myModel.trigger('change');
        }, 1000);
    },
    callback: function () {
        console.log('Callback reached!');
    }
});

//instantiate the router!
new Router();

//here's when router.initialize() is called.
Backbone.history.start();
```

NOTE: i used `setTimeout` to replace the use of `requirejs` but it shouldn't affect anything in this example.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KLCZ/

Comment: Thank you for the tips and the code example. However, translated to my solution with requirejs, it doens't work. Please see my more complete in my edited question, this is actual code from my project.

Comment: can you try `console.log(self, this)` in your router or `console.log(myRouter)` to see what those are? also there's a typo in your code. `var myRouter = new MyRouter()`. I assume you are starting your app by doing `new App()` since it's a View.

Comment: Sure! `console.log(self, this)` prints the router object and then `undefined`, followed by the same `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: Hm...`MyRouter` should be defined in your `window.App` view...could you make a jsfiddle or something that replicates your issue?